# Viewing Shared With Permissions on folder for Contributors compared to SCA

Tags: 2013, permissions, security, folder

We are wondering why some users with 'Contribute' permissions would see different 'Shared With' permissions on a library folder compared to the SCA.

We have the 'Browse User Information  -  View information about users of the Web site. ' permission level turned on for Contributors.

We're hoping to have what the SCA (Site Collection Admin) sees and those in 'Contribute' SharePoint Groups see so contributors really know who will see their documents once placed in particular folders...and they won't have to ask the SCA every time to double check.

Please advise.

Comment: Are there SharePoint groups on the site that are set up to only let members view group membership? Maybe the SCA is in groups that some of your Contribute users are not and thus can see the people in these groups.

Comment: no, nothing specific to that permission level.